# addClass to <tr> in handlebar script

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, addclass

Is there a simple way to add a class to a table row within a handlebar script?

Right now i'm looping through JSON and want to add pagenumber class to all rows

```
for (var i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {

        if (i % 10 == 0 && i != 0) {
            pageNumber++;                             
        }
        $('.tableRow').addClass('page' + pageNumber);
        console.log("page" + pageNumber);
    }
```

.tableRow is a `<tr>` i my handlebar script

It all works fine but i can't add to that class. It work fine if i try to append to a class outside my script

HTML code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/includes/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="tab-container">

            <div class="tab-content">

                <div id="scriptData"></div>


                <script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">


                        <table class="table-look">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="Header">Some data</th>
                                    <th class="Header">Some data</th>
                                    <th class="Header">Some data</th>
                                    <th class="Header">Some data</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {{#each this}}
                                <tr class="tableRow">
                                    <td">{{data}}</td>
                                    <td>{{data}}</td>
                                    <td>{{data}}</td>
                    <td>{{data}}</td>                               
                                </tr>
                    {{/each}} 
                            </tbody>                           
                        </table>
                </script>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/libs/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="includes/js/libs/handlebars-v4.0.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen HandlebarJS banded around a bit, but haven't ever used it myself - so this seemed like a good opportunity to get to grips with it.

jQuery wont pick up on any elements within `<script id="..." type="text/x-handlebars-template">`.  You haven't got any DOM elements for jQuery to work with in there - you've just got some text. It's a bit confusing, because it *looks* like normal HTML elements - but its just text. It's a script.

You have 2 options - you can either:

- A: Loop through the DOM elements after your template has been rendered.
- B: Use Handlebar's [Block Expressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html)

Option A:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var source = $("#template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var html = template(context);
    $('#foo').html(html);
    $('.tableRow').each(function(idx,o){
        $(this).addClass('page'+Math.floor(idx/2));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/xzey0dnj/3/

Option B:

**Template**

```
<tr class = "tableRow {{#page-number}}page{{/page-number}}">
```

**JS**

```
var fooItemNumber = 0;
Handlebars.registerHelper('page-number', function(items, options) {
    var out = "page";
    return out + Math.floor(fooItemNumber++/2);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/xzey0dnj/5/

Comment: Must have been tired or something.
What solved the problem was, as you mentioned, moving the code below handlebars template script

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".table-look tr").each(function(index,row){
       // add your class here
       $(row).addClass("yourClass");
   });
});
```

Comment: the for loop is in a $(funtion(){ }

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.